# Calling opencv through Emgucv

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv, camera-calibration

I'm trying to use Emgucv in c# to decompose a projection matrix into a rotation matrix, a translation matrix and a camera matrix. I could easily do it with RQ-Factorization but I couldn't find it by inspecting Emgucv API reference.

Since Emgucv is a opencv wrapper I search opencv functions and I've found the following c++ functions:

```
void cvDecomposeProjectionMatrix(const CvMat *projMatrix, CvMat *cameraMatrix, 
     CvMat *rotMatrix, CvMat *transVect, CvMat *rotMatrX=NULL, CvMat *rotMatrY=NULL, 
     CvMat *rotMatrZ=NULL, CvPoint3D64f *eulerAngles=NULL)

void RQDecomp3x3(const Mat& M, Mat& R, Mat& Q)
```

The question is: Is there any way I can use these functions with Emgucv?

Comment: Is this C# or what? Tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

EmguCV is an opencv wrapper but right now the function you want to use is still not wrapped. 
You have two options:

1. Wrap it yourself taking a look at how CvInvokeCalib3d.cs (or maybe another class inside emgucv PInvoke folder) define opencv functions PInvoking
2. Ask on emgu forum to add it to emgucv svn for you